# Как в ruby создать структуру и поле name со значением 'value'?

Tags: data-structures, ruby

Как в ruby создать структуру и поле name со значением 'value'?
Нужно вызовом одной функции либо хотя бы .new(...).new(...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Struct.new(:name).new('value')
```

Answer (score 0):

В качестве структур в Ruby используется стандартный тип Hash (суть ассоц. массив):

```
{name: "value"}
```